# Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? on Jenkins

Tags: git, maven, ssl, github, jenkins

We were building a Maven project using Broadleaf Demosite Github repository, 
it was building fine and we were facing issues only on deploying it on a slave until 30th Dec 2014.

After that we started receiving the below error:

```
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

Please let us know when and how to change the SSL RSA keys? It will be helpful for us to proceed further.

```
FATAL: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:627)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:865)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:890)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1252)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:624)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:530)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.checkCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2198)
```

Answer (score 0):

That might be a bug of the [1.14.0 release if the git-client-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/releases), since [`gitclient/CliGitAPIImpl.java`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gitclient/CliGitAPIImpl.java) is no longer supposed to call `checkCredentials`.

See [commit 097e68b](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/commit/097e68b1a161f031c2cde0d36ee73cfa4e6f5ddc) by [Ivo Bellin Salarin (`nilleb`)](https://github.com/nilleb):

### Do not interactively ask for a password

> Replace the `checkCredentials` function with the native `core.askpass=true` git config variable.

Try and upgrade to 1.14.1 to see if the issue persists.

Note that, using an https url, any SSL setting should not matter.